# Hidden div appear on table option select

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a page with a form and questions of these forms are asked on two separate tables. I want to make the second table appear only if One, Two or Three is selected from the first table, and be invisible by default. If Zero is selected again, table 2 disappears again.

I got it to partially work with the code below, however I think my script is cancelling each other out. I can get it to work with One, Two or Three, but not all three selections. In this case, table 2 only appears when I select "Three", and nothing happens when Zero, One and Two is selected.

How would I go about changing the script to let it appear when One, Two or Three are selected and disappear when Zero is selected once again.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Numbers</td>
    <td>
      <select id="numbers" name="numbers">
         <option value="Zero" selected>0</option>
         <option value="One">1</option>
         <option value="Two">2</option>
         <option value="Three">3</option>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<span id="animals" style="display: none;"> 
  <table>
       <tr>
           <td>Animal</td>
           <td>
              <select id="animal" input name="animal">
                  <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
                  <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
                  <option value="Rabbit">Rabbit</option>
              </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</span>

<script>
document.getElementById('numbers').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value == 'One' ? 'inline' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('animals').style.display = style;
});
document.getElementById('numbers').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value == 'Two' ? 'inline' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('animals').style.display = style;
});
document.getElementById('numbers').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value == 'Three' ? 'inline' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('animals').style.display = style;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Array include, check code snippet.

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Numbers</td>
    <td>
      <select id="numbers" name="numbers">
         <option value="Zero" selected>0</option>
         <option value="One">1</option>
         <option value="Two">2</option>
         <option value="Three">3</option>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<span id="animals" style="display: none;"> 
  <table>
       <tr>
           <td>Animal</td>
           <td>
              <select id="animal" input name="animal">
                  <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
                  <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
                  <option value="Rabbit">Rabbit</option>
              </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</span>
<script>

function checkVals(val){
  if(!val) {
    val = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
  }
 
var allowed = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var check = allowed.includes(val);

if(check){
   document.getElementById('animals').style.display = 'block';
}else{
   document.getElementById('animals').style.display = 'none';
}

}

document.getElementById('numbers').addEventListener('change', function () {
var val = this.value;
checkVals(val);

});


window.onload="checkVals()";


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. But there is one minor issue, When I submit this form and go to the next page, but press back to get back to this page, the 2nd table is not showing, despite table one already selected the One, Two, or Three. Any work around for that?

Comment: then you have to put entire logic into a function that same function you have to check on `window.onload`  like `window.onload="checkVals(0)";`  so when page load/reload it will check the dropdown value and show/hide table.

Comment: Not very sure how I go about doing this, could you share a code I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write three event listeners. Just one can do this.

```
 document.getElementById('numbers').addEventListener('change', function () {
var style = (this.value == 'One' || this.value == 'Two' || this.value =='Three')  && (this.value != 'Zero') ? 'inline' : 'none';
document.getElementById('animals').style.display = style;
 });
```

Comment: `three` - needs to be `Three`, case sensitive. How ever for the person who asked this @Dil Marc , I would recommend naming values lowercase, use _ if necessary.

Comment: This works! Thanks. But there is one minor issue, When I submit this form and go to the next page, but press back to get back to this page, the 2nd table is not showing, despite table one already selected the One, Two, or Three. Any work around for that?